# Join two meshes together

Tags: mesh

[image: Here are two irregular mesh surfaces and I want to join them and make them a consistent surface, any idea how can I do it?Thanks a lot!!;)]

Here are two irregular mesh surfaces and I want to join them and make them a consistent surface, any idea how can I do it?Thanks a lot!!;)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can shrinkwrap one onto the other:

[image]

In the example above, the blue is projected onto the violet one. On the right, it appears to be the same mesh.

The shrinkwrap modifier uses "project" mode along Z with positive/negative.

It also uses a vertex group that is the key point because it will drive the parts which will be projected:

[image]

You need to weight paint this group:

[image]

Roughly paint the borders, then use "Weights/Smooth" from the menu to have a progressive effect for the shrinkwrap.

An example: [image]